# Necessary license for "Bot Channels Registration"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-authentication

does anyone know which license I need for executing bot channels registration?
I followed folling tutorial and my license (O365 Business Basic) is not sufficient: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon the link you provided in the question, I am not sure which channel would you like to add, and the link just describing how to create a bot service in azure portal. This action just need a subscription in your tenant so that you can [pay for your bot service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bot-services/).

If I misunderstood your mean, pls offer more details, thx.

[image]

==============================UPDATE============================

You can [create an account for free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?ref=microsoft.com&utm_source=microsoft.com&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=visualstudio).

If you haven't got a subscription, you'll see this page when visit bot service:
[image]

If you don't get a correct subscription, you may see error message when creating bot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the provided link. I want to add the Teams Channel (standard channel) 
Besides I only want to create the registration and need no app services as my bot is not hosted in Azure. What do you mean with "This action just need a subscription in your tenant"? 
I know that I need an Azure account, but I don't know which kind. I have office 365 business basic license and thought that some kind of azure is already included because I can open Azure Portal, go to Azure AD and register an app. But I cannot open bot channels registration as my license isn't sufficient.

Comment: Emmm, I think you can try this. Login in azure portal, and go to the bot services page, and click 'Add' then choose to create bot channels registration, on the creating page, if you can see error message under 'subscription' field, that means you need a correct subscripiton. And if you don't have a subscription till now, when you wanna visit 'bot service' in azure portal, you may see welcome page to help you creating a subscription. Pls note, in azure portal, you need a subscription to pay for your services but not in format of license. You can't just buy a license for bot.

Comment: OK, so it seems that I don't have a subscription as I see the welcome page. But do I really need a subscription? In your link "Azure Bot Services pricing" it is stated that for standard channels unlimited messages are for free. So is there a kind of "free account"? I don't mean the free trial...

Comment: You do need a subscription, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-a-registration-application) describes how to create it. And if you don't have a subscription, you even can't reach the creating website.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to ask again: If I create a free account then I get a test account with some services free for 30 days (incl. 170€ credit), and some other services free for 12 month and then some services free at all...is it correct?
Which of these services do I need for bot channels registration? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I am not a expert in pricing, I can just share my knowledge with you. First, if you haven't prepared to pay for the bot channel, pls don't binding credit card. And after you creating a free account, you have 170€ in total to use within 30 days. And when 30 days passed even you cost 0€ and have 170€ left, money will expire too. Of course, after creating an account, you now have a subscription, so you can use some of services that are free. I'm sure that bot service is not free. I'm not sure if you can understand, but if you just wanna a test, just starting the trail and don't bind credit card.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that it's not possible to create an account without credit card binding...at least not via the link provided.

Comment: Emm, I used to create an account successfully and felt puzzled for can't pay for subscription after 30 days, because I don't have a credit card to bind.... You used this link ? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/   .........  Yes I tried just now, it really asks me to enter a card.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will get an azure Id with credit card infos. 
in [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#register-your-web-service-with-the-bot-framework is written the following:
If you do register a bot using Microsoft Azure portal, you must have a Microsoft Azure account. You can create one for free. To verify your identity when you create an Azure account, you must provide a credit card, but it won't be charged; it's always free to create and use bots with Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0):

You no need Office365 licenses for Bot Services.
You can test you bot setting via "Test in Web Chat" feature
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#test-the-bot

Comment: It's the other way round. I have an office 365 license and now just need to add a bot. My bot should not be hosted in Azure so I shouldn't need Bot Services.